# Bayesian updating with conjugate prior (specific example)

Tags: bayesian, conjugate-prior

This question deals with Bayesian updating with conjugate prior.Suppose we have a prior distribution of **N~(5, 3)** and then we observe **5** data points **(8, 9, 10, 8, 7)** (assumed to be taken randomly from a N~(9, 3) distribution). What would be the posterior after these observations in the form of N~(x, y)? I read the Wikipedia article on conjugate priors, but I want to have a more precise understanding of how to solve this specific problem. If there is no way to solve it without assuming some things, can you please explain what needs to be known and solve under very simple assumptions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the likelihood? and what are the parameters?

Comment: If the information is all that is given to work with, is there any way to approximate the posterior?

Comment: @Kelly if you know that the data comes from N(9, 3) distribution, then there is no need to estimate anything since you know the parameters in advance (9, 3). What niandra82 was saying is that you need to specify priors and likelihood, what you did is you only specified prior for mean.

Comment: When you say N~(a,b) presumably that indicates a normal distribution with mean a ... but is b the variance or the standard deviation in this notation?

Comment: @ Glen_b: b is the variance. @Tim: Right, I should have been clearer. What I meant about where the data comes from is some hypothetical distribution that exists but that the agents have no idea what. Example would be someone trying to estimate the distribution of the height of everyone who lives in Town X. The person has some prior, and there is actual data about the distribution of height, but the person only observes the five data points. I'm not quite sure what the likelihood could be for this specific situation.

Comment: Would the question make more sense if I assumed that the likelihood of observing those five data points given the prior is 0.2?

Comment: @Kelly if you do not know the distribution of your data (i.e. you are not willing to assume it), then you cannot use classical Bayesian inference since for this you would need to assume a likelihood function (i.e. distribution) for your data. If you do not assume distribution for your data then what parameters you want to estimate? N(a,b) is prior for what?

Comment: I'm willing to assume that the distribution of my data is normal. N~(5, 3) would be the prior distribution with mean 5 and variance 3, and after observing 5 data points, I would like to update my mean and variance to x and y. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. In simple cases the idea is to perform inference on the *parameters* of the distribution the data are drawn from. Your priors are priors on the distribution of one or more parameters. I was assuming you were giving a prior on $\mu$.

Comment: I'm sorry that I misunderstood, I hadn't realized that a host of other assumptions were necessary for this seemingly simple problem. So in the example I gave about estimating the height of people in Town X, is there another statistical method typically used to formalize how a person's estimate of the mean would change after the observations? It seems like there must be some formal way of characterizing the belief update for these simple situations.

Comment: You can make much weaker assumptions in various ways but the explanation of how to do it becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that you are misunderstanding what Bayesian inference is about in general. Bayes theorem is

$$ \underbrace{p(\theta \mid X)}_\text{posterior} = \frac{\overbrace{p(X \mid \theta)}^\text{likelihood} \, \overbrace{p(\theta)}^\text{prior}}{\underbrace{p(X)}_\text{normalizing constant}} $$

To make it more concrete, you can estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ parameters from normal distribution (i.e. normal *likelihood*) using data $X$, assuming normal *prior* for $\mu$ with hyperparameters $\mu_0$ and $\sigma^2_0$, and uniform *prior* for $\sigma^2$ with hyperparameters $a$ and $b$, to obtain *posterior* distributions for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$:

$$
X \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu, \sigma^2) \\
\mu \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu_0, \sigma^2_0) \\
\sigma^2 \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(a,b)
$$

So *priors* are assigned to parameters of interest, not to data. You also have to specify assumed distribution of your data (*likelihood*). Finally, *posterior* is distribution over estimated parameters, so you need to specify what you are actually estimating.